# Keras: How is Accuracy Calculated for Multi-Label Classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm doing the Toxic Comment Text Classification Kaggle challenge.  There are 6 classes: `['threat', 'severe_toxic', 'obscene', 'insult', 'identity_hate', 'toxic']`.  A comment can be multiple of these classes so it's a multi-label classification problem.

I built a basic neural network with Keras as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(10000, 128, input_length=250))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(classes), activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I run this line:

```
model.fit(X_train, train_y, validation_split=0.5, epochs=3)
```

and get 99.11% accuracy after 3 epochs.

However, 99.11% accuracy is a good bit higher than the best Kaggle submission.  This makes me think I'm either (possibly both) a) overfitting or b) misusing Keras's accuracy.

1) Seems a bit hard to overfit when I'm using 50% of my data as a validation split and only 3 epochs.

2) Is accuracy here just the percentage of the time the model gets each class correct?

So if I output `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]` and the correct output was `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, my accuracy would be `5/6`?

After a bit of thought, I sort of think the `accuracy` metric here is just looking at the class my model predicts with highest confidence and comparing vs. ground truth.

So if my model outputs `[0, 0, 0.9, 0, 0, 0]`, it will compare the class at index 2 ('obscene') with the true value.  Do you think this is what's happening?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 19):

For multi-label classification, I think it is correct to use `sigmoid` as the activation and `binary_crossentropy` as the loss.

If the output is sparse multi-label, meaning a few positive labels and a majority are negative labels, the Keras `accuracy` metric will be overflatted by the correctly predicted negative labels. If I remember correctly, Keras does not choose the label with the highest probability.  Instead, for binary classification, the threshold is 50%.  So the prediction would be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`.  And if the actual labels were `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, the accuracy would be `5/6`.  You can test this hypothesis by creating a model that always predicts negative label and look at the accuracy.

If that's indeed the case, you may try a different metric such as [top_k_categorical_accuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/top_k_categorical_accuracy).

Another remote possibility I can think of is your training data. Are the labels y somehow "leaked" into x? Just a wild guess.

Comment: There is a `weighted_binary_crossentropy` loss function defined here for multi-label problems where there is a lot of negative predictions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/313922/198729. However I'm also looking for a `weighted_binary_accuracy` as well.

Comment: Also the `top_k_categorical_accuracy` doesn't seem to work in this case as what is the `top_k` for the truths if the truths are multi-hot encoded?

Answer (score 6):

You can refer to [Keras Metrics documentation](https://keras.io/metrics/) to see all metrics available (e.g. binary_accuracy). You can also create your own custom metric (and make sure it does exactly what you expect). I wanted to make sure [neurite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686741/2113717) was right about how the accuracy is computed, so this is what I did (note: `activation="sigmoid"`) :

```
from keras.metrics import binary_accuracy
def custom_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    return binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)

# ...

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[
    "accuracy",
    "binary_accuracy",
    "categorical_accuracy",
    "sparse_categorical_accuracy",
    custom_acc
])
```

Running the training you will see that the `custom_acc` is always equal to the `binary_accuracy` (and therefore to the `custom_acc`).

Now you can refer to the [Keras code on Github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2ad932ba4ea501af7c3163573fce994ef878d8ef/keras/metrics.py#L26) to see how it is computed:

```
K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

Which confirm what [neurite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686741/2113717) said (i.e. If the prediction is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]` and the actual labels were `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, the accuracy would be `5/6`).

Comment: I added all potential metrics to determine which one was used and compare the results. It was only experimental.