# What is the expected result of top_k_categorical_accuracy in multi-label classification?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, multilabel-classification

I have a multi-label classification problem, where each data point has exactly 3 labels (out of many labels, say 1000). In my model, I pick the top 5 predicted labels.

Here is a snippet of model code:

```
def top_labels(true_label, pred_label):
    return tf.keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy(true_label, pred_label, k=5))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(10000, 128, input_length=250))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(classes), activation='sigmoid'))    
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', top_labels])
```

My question is: what is the expected top_k_categorical_accuracy outcome?

If my training data is the following:

```
data_idx   features      true_labels 
1           blabla          2,3,4      
2           blabla          1,2,3
```

And the prediction result is

```
data_idx   top_5 predicted_labels
1           1,4,5,8,9
2           4,5,6,7,8
```

I have two guesses:

1. 0.5: because for 1st data point, there is one match of label (label 4), and for 2nd data point, no label is matched.
2. 1/6: because for 1st data point, there is one label match out of 3 true labels, and for 2nd data point, no label is matched out of 3.

I feel like the answer is 1), but I'm confused after testing the following code:

```
y_true = [[1, 1, 0, 0]] # assume 2 labels for a data point

y_pred = [[0, 0.9, 0.05, 0.95]]

m = tf.keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=3)

m.numpy() # result: array([0.], dtype=float32)
```

So it looks like top_k_categorical_accuracy can only handle **one** true label instead of multiple true labels (it takes the first true label only and ignore the rest).

However, I'm not sure if setting the activation of the last layer as `sigmoid` changes the evaluation behavior.

Can someone clarify a bit please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal `top_k_categorical_accuracy` definition for multilabel classification as far as I know. Your observation about the metric discarding all values of `y_true` but the first one hints that using it for multilabel classification probably results in undefined behaviour.

"Accuracy" for multilabel is usually interpreted as binary accuracy for each individual label. Since label outputs are often sparse, accuracy alone returns high values due to the prevalence of true negatives.

Typical metrics for multilabel are the ones used for imbalanced binary prediction (e.g. [micro/macro F1 score](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score)) and the [Hamming distance](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/HammingLoss).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if your explanation for `top_k_categorical_accuracy` is correct. Here is a counter example: `y_true = [[1, 0, 0, 1]]`, `y_pred=[[0.95, 0.9, 0.05, 0]]` with `k=3`. Accoding to your definition the result should be false because it's 1 in 3rd position of `y_true`, but not 1 in `y_pred`. However the result is 1. Also I believe `top_k_categorical_accuracy` is reasonable as suggested by a few posts such as https://theailearner.com/2019/07/15/multi-label-classification/ ?

Comment: You are right, your explanation of taking only the 1st true label is correct. I'll amend the answer.
About your blog post, I guess you should check for extra references on using `top_k` for multilabel. This is only one example (not "a few"), and the first I've ever seen. Given the function's behaviour, chances are it's just wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Here is another post for top_k_category metric: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686217/keras-how-is-accuracy-calculated-for-multi-label-classification/50686741#50686741 (the second answer, wanted to include it above but restricted by comment length :) )

Comment: Yeah, seems like the second comment from the answer touches the same problems you are facing. I found an interesting thread in the TF github issues, check all links if you wish to go down the rabbit hole: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28074